# Are these correct?

Tags: electronic-configuration

We were tasked to write the electronic configuration of the elements in the third energy level.

My answers are:

1s2 2s2 2p6 3s1

1s2 2s2 2p6 3s2

1s2 2s2 2p6 3s2 3p1

1s2 2s2 2p6 3s2 3p2

1s2 2s2 2p6 3s2 3p3

1s2 2s2 2p6 3s2 3p4

1s2 2s2 2p6 3s2 3p5

1s2 2s2 2p6 3s2 3p6

But I am not sure if these are in the third energy level cause my logic is new period in the periodic table = new energy level so I just wrote all electronic configuration of elements in the third period.

Answer (score 1):

So you were asked to write the electron configurations for the elements in the third energy level? I am a little confused. **I think elements do not reside on energy levels, electrons do.** OR, were you asked to write the electron configurations for the elements in the third period of the periodic table? If this is case, your answer should be correct from sodium to argon. I am not aware of any elements violate the Aufbau Principle in the third period.

If you were actually asked to write the electron configurations for the elements containing electrons reside in the third energy level (n=3), I think you need to write the elements starting from sodium all the way to the end, Oganesson.

You can use this electronic periodic table to check your work. https://ptable.com/#Electrons